# Hiding an Account record from searches and reporting?

Tags: reporting

Is there any way to hide certain Accounts from the Global Chatter search and reporting?

Essentially I want to "deactivate" an Account, so the information is still there, but it doesn't show up in reports or searches.

The only way I've thought to do this is by setting Account to Private and then opening up all "Active" Accounts via Sharing Rule.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the answer, OWD set to private, and make sure the owner is segregated in the role hierachy, so it doesn't become visible to someone higher in the structure.

Comment: That "someone" should usually be either an administrator or an integration user, if you have one. Someone that won't mind, or that it won't make a difference to (admins see all records anyways). For organizations where direct deletions are deemed inappropriate, the user can own all the records, and you can simply invoke criteria-based sharing to expose records, although this can be a confusing setup.